# Axios with django server on localhost

Tags: django, react-native, axios

Trying to access django server on localhost from my react native app. All I get is Network Error, which doesn't say much. Tried changing info.plist file as suggested in other answers on stack, tried changing firewall settings and so on.

Answer (score -1):

The thing that worked and solved all my problems was changing the url on axios to my local ip and running django server with command: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0` which to my understanding will accept any connection to the server.